# Simple file upload page not working

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I'm trying to add a simple file upload page on my site. Whenever I submit the form, it says "This field is required" above the file selector, as if it's not passing it. Here is my form, model, and view.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):

    MURRMACMOD = "MMM"
    CUBE67 = "C67"
    CUBE20 = "C20"
    VDINCONN = "VDC"
    IMPACT20 = "I20"
    IMPACT67 = "I67"
    CAT_CHOICES = (
        (MURRMACMOD, 'Murrelektronik Mac Module'),
        (CUBE67, 'Cube67/Cube67'),
        (CUBE20, 'Cube20'),
        (VDINCONN, 'Valve DIN Connectors'),
        (IMPACT20, 'Impact 20'),
        (IMPACT67, 'Impact 67')
    )

    article = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = forms.FileField()
    cat = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CAT_CHOICES)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class File(models.Model):

    article = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField()
    cat = models.CharField()
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

from files.forms import UploadFileForm

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()

    ctxt_dict = {
        'form': form,
    }
    context = RequestContext(request, ctxt_dict)
    return render_to_response('upload.html', context_instance=context)
```

I would love some help guys, thanks.

EDIT:
Here is the template.

```
{% if user.is_staff %}
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
{% else %}
{% endif %}
</form>
```

Comment: May you kindly add also your template (at least the form part and all potentially form-related javascipt code)? Thanks :)

Comment: @furins I didn't think it mattered, but I added it.

Comment: Now that I see it I agree, it does not matter :) thank you - PS you should close the form tag inside the if..else..endif statement or you'll have an orphan close tag

Comment: :P Sure thing. I just don't see why it's not working.

Comment: form.save is not enough. You have to instantiate your class with request.FILES content as shown in point 4 of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example

Answer (score 1):

In Django Template , if you are trying to render a form that has a filefield . You must pass replace

form method="post" action="">

with

form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

[loop over forms in formset and a list at same time + FileField required error :django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319387/loop-over-forms-in-formset-and-a-list-at-same-time-filefield-required-error-d/15319510#15319510)